# Use Layout as OverlayItem on MapView?

Tags: android, overlay, android-mapview

Is it possible to use a layout defined in XML as an OverlayItem to be added to a MapView instead of just a single drawable?  I have several Overlays being drawn on the map but they are just single images, I would now like to place Overlays that are more complex objects instead of just a simple drawable.

I am planning on drawing a marker with a dynamic image inside it (just a friend locator type thing), where each marker has a different picture inside.

Is adding these as OverlayItems the way to go about it or do I need to add each one to the MapView as a child view (this seems like it would be inefficient)?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar - draw Google Maps style balloons with custom views inside them onto the map. I tried overriding the draw() of an OverlayItem, and drawing the layout I'd defined in XML that way. The problem was in coverting the View to a Drawable to draw onto the MapView canvas meant I lost all event handling capabilities of the Layout so things like buttons etc. did not work properly. If you don't have any events on the images to worry about then this could work, you'll just need to inflate your view using the current Activity's LayoutInflater (activity.getLayoutInflater()), measure and lay it out as described under the 'How Android Draws Views' page on the android developers site (couldn't post a link due to new user restrictions, sorry!), and finally call buildDrawingCache() and getDrawingCache() on your View to get it as a Bitmap. This can then be drawn onto the Canvas passed the draw() method of a subclass of Overlay that you've built.

I actually went for the second approach you suggested (adding each one as a child view to MapView, using MapView.LayoutParams to hover the layout over the OverlayItem in question) in the end. I only had one child view to worry about though so I wasn't too worried about the efficiency here, it might be more of a problem to you if that is actually something to be concerned about (it might be worth testing first though). There's a small writeup of what I did [here](http://www.actionshrimp.com/2011/05/speech-bubble-popups-containing-a-view-for-android-mapview/) with a bit more detail.

Finally you might want to look at [android-mapviewballoons](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)'s approach to this, which is well worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a layout as a Marker on a map by converting the layout to a drawable. Here's a `bitmapFromView` function taken from [this tutorial](http://nadavfima.com/android-snippet-inflate-a-layout-draw-to-a-bitmap/):

```
public static Bitmap bitmapFromView(View layout, int width, int height, Context context) {
    // Create a new bitmap and a new canvas using that bitmap
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    layout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    // Supply measurements
    layout.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    // Apply the measures so the layout would resize before drawing.
    layout.layout(0, 0, layout.getMeasuredWidth(), layout.getMeasuredHeight());
    // and now the bmp object will actually contain the requested layout
    canvas.drawBitmap(layout.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, new Paint());
    return bmp;
}
```

I use the method to add the bitmap as a Marker like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.MY_LAYOUT, null);
Bitmap markerBitmap = bitmapFromView(layout, MY_WIDTH, MY_HEIGHT, context);

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
            .title(MY_TITLE)
            .position(MY_POSITION)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(markerBitmap));
map.addMarker(markerOptions);
```